# Reading from file/array. No values. No errors

Tags: java

Any ideas what I am missing here? I am reading from a file array. The values in the text file don't get stored and there is no output. All I get is "names and totals" but no values.

I don't know.

```
private int[] totals;
private String[] names;
private String[] list;

private int count;


public void readData() throws IOException {

    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("cookies.txt"));

    //create the arrays
    totals = new int[count];
    names = new String[count];
    list = new String[count];

    //read in each pair of values
    String quantityString = input.readLine();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        names[i] = input.readLine();
        list[i] = input.readLine();
        quantityString = input.readLine();
        totals[i] = Integer.parseInt(quantityString);
    }

}

public void display() {
    System.out.println("names           totals")
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        System.out.println(list[i] + "        \t " + names[i] + "        \t" + totals[i]);
}

//called to compute and print the result
public void printResults() {

    //find the best teacher
    int maxIndex = 0;
    int maxValue = 0;

    //for each record stores
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        //if we have a new MAX value so far, update variables
        if (maxValue < totals[i]) {
            maxValue = totals[i];
            maxIndex = i;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show the complete code with better formatting. What is assigned to 'count'

Comment: I took a guess when doing the formatting.  I ended the if block, for-loop, and method.  It could have been early.  It'd be best to put your entire source code here so that we could see what specifically is going on/going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never give the variable `count` a value, so it initialized to `0` by Java. This means that your arrays are of size `0` also.

So since `count` is zero, you never read anything from the file, which is why nothing is stored in your arrays and also why nothing is printed out.

**Example: Reading a File line-by-line**

```
// create temporary variable to hold what is being read from the file
String line = "";

// when you don't know how many things you have to read in use a List
// which will dynamically grow in size for you
List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<Integer>();

// create a Reader, to read from a file
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("cookies.txt"));

// read a full line, this means if you line is 'Smith 36' 
// you read both of these values together
while((line = input.readLine()) != null) 
{
   // break 'Smith 36' into an array ['Smith', '36']
   String[] nameAndValue = line.split("\\s+"); 

   names.add(nameAndValue[0]);                   // names.add('Smith')
   values.add(Integer.parseInt(nameAndValue[1]); // values.add(36);
}
```

Comment: Well do you know how many things you need to read in? If so, set count to that number.

Comment: i apologize for asking such a question but i've been going crazy for a couple of hours now. i'm new to java or coding.

Comment: 26
Smith
3
Courtney
5
Tuohy
8
Malerba
7
Wynne
5
Amendola
8
Byrnes
9
Conyers
5
Davis
4
DiPaoli
10
DiLonardo
12
Donofrio
15
Harris
5
Heyer
8
Henselder
9
Quesada
8
Sgherza
6
Yousef
19
Zambrano
18
Kumuyi
7
Aliberti
6
Alvarez
10
Chiara
12
Maloney
5
Stix
5
Merritt
22

Comment: @JaneSmith And there are newlines after each number name pair?

Comment: where do i set that number at?

Comment: i don't know what you mean. my part 1 is just suppose to read and display the data...part 2 has more data to add

Comment: teacherClass c = new teacherClass(); ...should I put the value in the prenthesis?

Comment: @JaneSmith What I am saying is unless you no ahead of time how many entries are in the file you cannot use a for-loop to read because you don't know when to stop. I will post an example in a minute or two.